# ( Google Cloud platform) I accidentally set up a firewall inside the Linux VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sshd

I cannot access the ssh console at all. Is there a way for me to download the disk inside the cloud platform?

Comment: This article might help you on recovering from UFW lockout. Steps are similar for other firewalls. The simplest method is to create a startup script and reboot your instance. The steps to mount the disk on another VM are also covered. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get onto the VM through a serial console:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Alternatively, mount the disk on another, VM revert the change and then put it back on the original VM.